# Call global javascript function from jquery click bind function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have global function which gives the value of request parameter in url.
I am trying to find the value of a parameter from a jquery binding function. But somehow for a request param 'trk' this function doesnt seem to work. The code for these funtions is below

```
function get(name){
        if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search)) {
              return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
             }
        }


    $(".floorLandingBanner").click(function() {
             var bannerSubHeading ='';
             bannerSubHeading = get('trk');
             console.log(bannerSubHeading);
         });
```

bannerSubHeading is coming as an empty string even for url with request param 'trk'.

Using the above function for varaibles 'utm_launch' etc. seems to work fine.

The following code works perfectly fine. But incase of 'trk' it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(get("utm_source")!=null) {
         s.pageName="UTMLaunch";
         s.eVar47=get("utm_source");
         s.eVar48=get("utm_campaign");
         s.eVar49=get("utm_medium");
         s.eVar50=get("utm_content");
         s.eVar51=get("utm_term");

     }
```

Update:
The reason for the issue was that the variable was being tracked in location.search which provides the query string. Instead where I needed to search trk was in the href of the selected div which was not being reflected in the current url.
what I needed to do was declare a new function

```
function get(url,name){
            if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(url)) {
                  return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
                 }
            }
```

and call this function in the following manner

```
get($(this).attr("href"), 'trk');
```

Comment: i'm sorry about careless answer

Comment: Is it because of regex not working in `trk` case?

Comment: yup that was the case. But I have updated the question after figuring out my mistake.

Comment: get word is reserved, so try to use another func name

Comment: it`s just tip, maybe not related to your question